# Where is the default Release Retention stored in SQL

Tags: tfs, release, release-management, retention

Where is the default release retention stored at in the DefaultCollection SQL database?  I have 300+ team projects and I need to change the default retention policy on all projects.  I was hoping to find the correct table in SQL and just executing a statement to update the retention policy across all projects.
Thanks.

Comment: You should **never** directly alter the team project collection databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the `RetentionPolicy` stored in table `tbl_DefinitionEnvironment`:

[image]

> But, please notice, we don't suggest handle database directly. It's
>   recommended to modify the release definition on the web access. If you
>   insist on handle database, be sure you have **full** backup of
>   database. It's important.